# How do airplanes with thrust lines above CG still fly without a down pitch moment?

Tags: aircraft-design, thrust

Mainly the Icon A5. I remember trying to make an RC aircraft similar to it, but the moment i'd spin up the motors the aircraft would understandably pitch down. i couldnt fly it at all.

So how do these planes with thrust lines way above the CG fly? I've seen some people say its an interaction of the airflow above the horizontal stabilizers, but it hasn't yet clicked with me.

[image: Icon A5 from the side, thrust line way above CG (& the motors rotated in such a way it should pitch the nose down even more!)]

[image: how i assumed this would work]

[image: w.e.]

Comment: There are a number of airplanes where the horizontal stabilizer provides a significant downforce in flight, either by being airfoil shaped, or angled downward, or both.  The tuck-under tendency is greatest at high thrust and low speed, so the elevator will be designed to ensure sufficient pitch authority for that, but the plane should be designed so that in cruise, the aerodynamic downforce of the tail equals the nose-over torque of the high engine mounting.  I suspect high-engine aircraft often have larger than usual trim tabs as well to ease pilot workload.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you generally do with a high thrust line is place the horizontal stabilizer surface directly in the propeller wash to help offset some of the trim change caused by thrust changes.

When you add power, the increased velocity over the tail induces a nose-up trim change by increasing trim down-force, which compensates for some of the nose down trim change induced by the increasing thrust on an axis that is above the C of G.

The Lake Buccaneer uses a substantial semi-rigid (that is, adjustable fixed) trimming surface at the outboard ends of the stabilizer, to create an instantaneous increase in trimming downforce to offset the nose down thrust line effect.  It helps a lot with the Buccaneer, but doesn't eliminate the thrust effects entirely, and adding power still causes a pitch down, and vice versa. Just much milder than without the Buccaneer's stabilizer configuration.

The A5 appears to have the thrust line much closer to the vertical C of G than the Buccaneer, and the horizontal tail appears to be sufficiently within the propeller wash to provide some of the pitch offset effect, to the extent that thrust effects on trim are a problem with the A5 (probably much milder than the Buccaneer).

So if you stick the horizontal tail directly behind the propeller in your RC model, you will reduce the nose tuck with power, but you probably won't be able to eliminate it and you're going to have to add an additional channel for an adjustable pitch trimming surface if it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 5):

> How do airplanes with thrust lines above CG still fly without a down pitch moment?

For straight horizontal flight, the **total** pitching moment needs to be zero. With a thrust line above CoG, the thrust vector will always cause a nose-down moment which will need to be compensated by an aerodynamic nose-up moment - trim the nose up with a tail-down aerodynamic force.

Which is fine for constant thrust, it’s just a nuisance that the plane needs to be trimmed every time that the thrust is set to a different level. Indeed placing the horizontal tail in the prop wash will provide the necessary change in trim to an extent.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution for a related topic, what if thrust line is below the CG (Sukhoi Su-27):

By tilting the nozzle down to point the thrust vector to CG:

[image: 5-43]

At some stage of the design evolution, the engine core is tilted 2 degrees on the front and the afterburner is tilted down 3 degrees on the rear. In total, the engine has a 5 degree bend in the middle.

[SU-27 Fighter: Beginning of Story: Part 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MRF1POK)

by Nikolay Gordyukov Pavel Plunsky, Vladimir Antonov, Vyacheslav Zenkin, Ildar Bedretdinov

(Picture is taken from a Chinese translation of this book, Chapter 5, Figure 5-43. Top to bottom, 1972 1973 and 1976 layouts.)

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the Chinese translation? I would be interested in it

Comment: @GrantCurell ISBN 9787516511565 and ISBN 9787516511572

Comment: 謝謝我總是需要新的書來練習我工程師的詞匯